# How to set primary key in SQLCreateTable to be auto_increment

Tags: databaselink

I'm trying to create a table using SQLCreateTable. What I need is auto incremented primary key. My table will be growing in time and I don't want to check previous value of primary key every time I will be adding new row. 
Right now my primary key can't be empty, so in each SQLInsert I need to specify it.
Is there any chance to do it without SQLExecute?

Comment: the details of auto-incrementation are unfortunately database-engine specific. In some cases you might get away without SQLExecute, but in others not. Which system are you using? Why do you want to avoid SQLExecute?

Comment: I'm using HSQL, so I need INTEGER IDENTITY. Thank You for a tip about database-engine.

Comment: I'm not sure, it is a while since I have used HSQL, but I'm afraid that you will need an SQLExecute with the matching `CEATE TABE` statement there. SQLite e.g. does automatically set autoincrement for integer primary keys, so there you could get away with just `SQLCreateTable`.